# The Weak topology on an infinite-dimensional space is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X $ be  an infinite-dimensional normed space.  I want to prove that the weak topology on $X$ is not metrizable.  This is my solution:

> Assume that there is a metric $d$ on $X$ inducing the weak topology, and consider $U_n:=\{x\in X: d(x,0)<\frac{1}{n}\}$.  We know each $U_n$ is weakly open and so will be unbounded (for the strong topology), and thus $$\forall (n)\exists (x_n\in U_n) \:\text{s.t.}\: \|x_n\|\geq n$$ But $x_n\to 0$ in $(X, d)$, so that $x_n \stackrel{w}{\to}0$, and hence $(x_n)$ is bounded. Contradiction.

Is this the right solution?

Please give me a reference about the other solutions.

Comment: Looks correct to me (even though I'm not fully sure whether the results you cite hold for arbitrary infinite-dimensional normed spaces or just Banach ones). In fact, something stronger is true: the weak topology on an infinite-dimensional normed space can never be first-countable (which is a weaker condition than metrizability). See, for example, Theorem 6.26 in [Aliprantis–Border (2006, p. 237)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=hu&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @triple_sec The topology of a locally convex space is metrizable if and only if it is first-countable. So the result you quoted appears to be stronger, but is not really.

Comment: Your argument is correct. I don't think there is a simpler proof.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get this off the unanswered list: the proof is fine.  You might clarify at the end that "bounded" is with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$, and that this follows from the uniform boundedness principle.

More details can be found at [Why the weak topology is never metrizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893495/why-the-weak-topology-is-never-metrizable)

Other questions about this theorem, stolen from the Related list:

- [Weak topology on an infinite-dimensional normed vector space is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424876/weak-topology-on-an-infinite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-not-metrizable?rq=1)
- [Weak topology is not metrizable: what's wrong with this proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814174/weak-topology-is-not-metrizable-whats-wrong-with-this-proof?rq=1)
- [Metrizability of the weak topology $\sigma(E,E')$ of a normed space $E$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913169/metrizability-of-the-weak-topology-sigmae-e-of-a-normed-space-e?rq=1)
- [Is the weak topology sequential on some infinite-dimensional Banach space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029853/is-the-weak-topology-sequential-on-some-infinite-dimensional-banach-space?rq=1)
- [Weak$*$ topology is metrizable iff $X$ is finite dimensional.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486297/weak-topology-is-metrizable-iff-x-is-finite-dimensional?rq=1)
- [Weak topology is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815233/weak-topology-is-not-metrizable?rq=1)
- [Why the weak topology is never metrizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893495/why-the-weak-topology-is-never-metrizable)