# Properties of the sequential space $(X,\tau_{seq})$ generated by $\tau$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space. Denote by $\tau_{seq}$ the topology on $X$ whose closed sets are the sequentially $\tau$-closed subsets of $X$. 
 From my understanding, the space $(X,\tau_{seq})$ is a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

> Is there a book/paper where I can read more about the topological properties of $\tau_{seq}$ or sequential spaces in general?

The [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sequential+topological+space) for sequential spaces mentions about their categorical properties which I am not interested in. I would like to know properties like *metrizability* or if such spaces are *completely regular/normal*.

More specifically, I am interested in the space $(X,w_{seq})$, where $X$ is a Banach space and $w$ its weak topology (generated by bounded linear functionals). This case is related to the sequential lower semicontinuity of some integral functional in calculus of variation that I am studying. Any account that covers only this case would suffice for my purpose.

PS. This question is a follow-up question to another one I asked on Mathoverflow earlier [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338910/properties-of-the-topology-of-sequential-convergence-tau-seq).

Comment: I just used google too many results, here are two that might be relevant https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2018-146-04/S0002-9939-2017-13843-X/home.html and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029853

Comment: @Mirko Thank you but unfortunately those are not what I want. The only source so far that seems to contain what I want is "Topologie e strutture di convergenza" by Dolcher but, sadly, it is in Italian and I don't speak or read Italian.