# Weak topology is not metrizable

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, weak-topology, metrizability

I'm now reading some properties of weak topology, I have some problems which may related to the topology property in non-metrizable space ($E $  is a Banach Space):

1. I know that $E^*$ with weak* topology is not a metrizable space, but the classical results shows that $B_{E^*} = \{f:\|f\|_{E^*} \leq 1 \}$ is metrizable in weak* topology provided $E$ is separable. How can we explain this contradiction?
2. Let $S = \{x: \|x\| = 1, x \in E\}$, then the closure of $S$ in weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$ is $B_E = \{x:\|x\| \leq 1, x \in E\}$. However a result shows that If we want to find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ s.t. $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$,$\|x_n\| = 1$, we often need the extra condition that $E^*$ be separable or reflexive.  This two results seem a contradiction to me.
3. Prove the following result: if $M \subset E$ is a linear subspace, $f_0 \in E^*$, then there exists some $g_0 \in M^\perp$ such that:
   \begin{equation*}
   \inf_{g \in M^\perp} \|f_0 - g\| = \|f_0 - g_0\|
   \end{equation*}

Comment: It would make it easier for people to answer your questions if you deleted this post and turned it into three separate questions.

Comment: I think there is something common in these three questions because they all need some understanding of the fact of non-metrizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That the unit ball, $ B_{E^*} $  is metrizable, does not mean that $E^*$ is. Actually, all balls in $E^*$ are metrizable, but you cannot define a global metric, that generates the weak* topology. So there is really no contradiction here.
2. Remember that $E$ endowed with the weak topology is not first countable, and thus it is not sufficient to consider sequences when finding closures. In general, there only needs to be a net converging weakly to $0$.
3. Let $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}\subset M^\perp$ be a sequence such that $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert f_0-g_n \rVert=\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\lVert f_0-g \rVert.
   $$
   Clearly $g_n$ is norm bounded, and we may assume, by possibly passing to a subnet, $(g_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$, that $(g_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ converges to some $ g_0\in M^\perp$ in the weak* topology. Now using that the norm is weak* lower semicontinuous we have $$
   \inf_{g\in M^\perp}\lVert f_0-g \rVert=\lim_{\alpha\in A}\lVert f_0-g_\alpha \rVert=\liminf_{\alpha\in A}\lVert f_0-g_\alpha \rVert\geq \lVert f_0-g_0 \rVert.
   $$
   On the other hand, it is obvious that $\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\lVert f_0-g \rVert\leq
   \lVert f_0-g_0 \rVert$, since $g_0\in M^\perp$. So $ \inf_{g\in M^\perp}\lVert f_0-g \rVert= \lVert f_0-g_0 \rVert. $

Comment: Why does $\{g_n\}$ necessarily contain a convergent subsequence? From Banach-Alaoglu we know that the closed unit ball $B_{E^*}$ is compact in weak* topology, but it is not necessarily sequential compact. We need more condition like that $X$ is a separable space, to conclude that we can actually choose a subsequence.

Comment: You are right, but you can just take a subnet instead. I will correct it in the answer.